# SOAP Service missing sent 'parameters'

Tags: c#, php, soap, parameters

**PHP:**

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$ArrayOfString = array(0 => "first", 1 => "second");

$header = new SoapHeader($wsdl, 'AuthenticationHeader', $authentication);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$values = $client->GetInfo(array($ArrayOfString));
print_r($values);
```

That's invokes that in **C#**

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[SoapHeader("ServiceAuthenticationHeader")]
public InfoResponse GetInfo(List<string> text)
{
}
```

After I invoke method - parameter (*`List<string>` text*) is **NULL**.
Any ideas, because all day I watched, tested every methods from internet, but not effect!?
Thank you!

Comment: That is not going to just be a `List<string>`. Use the wsdl and `xsd.exe` to generate the type(s) you need for the parameter. Or  you can always just take it in as xml and parse it manually with `XDocument`.

Comment: thanks....example?

Comment: Xsd.exe is well documented.